# SQL Error 1822 : Failed to add the foreign key constaint. Missing index for constraint BUT the index EXISTS

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to add a foreign key with 2 columns.

Here is the DDL of table referencing the foreign key :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sf_file_category` (
  `id_file_category`        INT                         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name`                    VARCHAR(45)
                            CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
                            COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci' NOT NULL,
  `file_type`               ENUM('document', 'image', 'video', 'archive')
                            CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
                            COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci' NULL,
  `id_file_category_parent` INT UNSIGNED                NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_file_category`),
  INDEX `fk_sf_file_category_sf_file_category1_idx` (`id_file_category_parent` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_sf_file_category_sf_file_idx` (`id_file_category` ASC, `file_type` ASC)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

DDL of table who owns the foreign key :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sf_file` (
  `id_file`           INT UNSIGNED                NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fullpath`          VARCHAR(100)
                      CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
                      COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci' NOT NULL,
  `basename`          VARCHAR(45)
                      CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
                      COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci' NOT NULL,
  `accesskey`         CHAR(8)
                      CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
                      COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci' NOT NULL,
  `file_type`         ENUM('document', 'image', 'video', 'archive')
                      CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
                      COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci' NULL,
  `name`              VARCHAR(45)
                      CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
                      COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci' NULL,
  `description`       VARCHAR(255)
                      CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
                      COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci' NULL,
  `id_aircraft_image` SMALLINT UNSIGNED           NULL,
  `id_aircraft`       SMALLINT UNSIGNED           NULL,
  `id_file_category`  INT UNSIGNED                NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_file`),
  INDEX `fk_sf_file_sf_file_category1_idx` (`id_file_category` ASC, `file_type` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_sf_file_sf_aircraft1_idx` (`id_aircraft` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_sf_file_sf_aircraft2_idx` (`id_aircraft_image` ASC)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
  COLLATE = latin1_general_ci;
```

Trying to execute following foreign key syntax :

```
ALTER TABLE `sf_file` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_sf_file_sf_file_category1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_file_category` , `file_type`)
  REFERENCES `sf_file_category` (`id_file_category` , `file_type`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

But I get this error  : 
ERROR: Error 1822: Failed to add the foreign key constaint. Missing index for constraint 'fk_sf_file_sf_file_category1' in the referenced table 'sf_file_category'.

I assume he means the INDEX `fk_sf_file_sf_file_category1_idx` (`id_file_category` ASC, `file_type` ASC) that is already created in the table sf_file_category.

Is there any particular way for creating multiple field foreign key that I am missing ?

Comment: Executes without any problem on my end.

Comment: type of fields and their collation should match

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos which tool you used on your end ? Tried this only statement but still getting the "[HY000][1215] Cannot add foreign key constraint" ...

Comment: I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3, whereas the server version is 5.6.26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentionned @Pankaj Pandey, my field declaration didn't match exactly, `id_file_category` being `NULL` on a table and `NOT NULL` on another will prevent foreign key creation.